# odata v4 unable to select property of complex type within another complex type (using expand)

Tags: c#, json, select, odata, expand

I’ve got an model on which I have Items (root), then a complex Type (Manufacturing), embedding another complex type (location, named Factory below).

When expanding Manufacturing, all is working as expected:

```
https://localhost/Inextrace/Items('ABC123456789')?$select=Code&$expand=Manufacturing($select=Factory)
```

However, when I try to select only one property of the complex type location (Factory), it says it is not supported. Any workaround to achieve this?

```
https://localhost/Inextrace/Items('ABC123456789')?$select=Code&$expand=Manufacturing($select=Factory/Code)
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. A path within the select or expand query option is not supported.","innererror":{
      "message":"A path within the select or expand query option is not supported.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.SelectExpandNode.ValidatePathIsSupported(ODataPath path)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.GetPropertiesToIncludeInQuery(SelectExpandClause selectExpandClause, IEdmEntityType entityType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet, IEdmModel model, ISet`1& autoSelectedProperties)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.ProjectElement(Expression source, SelectExpandClause selectExpandClause, IEdmEntityType entityType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.BuildPropertyContainer(IEdmEntityType elementType, Expression source, Dictionary`2 propertiesToExpand, ISet`1 propertiesToInclude, ISet`1 autoSelectedProperties, Boolean isSelectingOpenTypeSegments)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.ProjectElement(Expression source, SelectExpandClause selectExpandClause, IEdmEntityType entityType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.GetProjectionLambda()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(IQueryable queryable)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.ApplyTo(IQueryable queryable, ODataQuerySettings settings, IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplySelectExpand[T](T entity, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas to select only some field of the Factory?

I'm C# .Net using and the following versions of nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.OData v5.8.0
- Microsoft.OData.Code v6.14.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi v5.2.3

Regards,
Nicolas Stübi